# How to move antd Dropdown component to the right corner within a Col component?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I'm using the antd library and I have a Dropdown component inside a Col component. I want to move the Dropdown component to the right corner of the Col component, but I can't seem to figure out how to do it.

I use Col instead of Card since Card has implemented padding for its body.

Here is my code:

```js
<Col
  className="bg-white border d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center flex-column"
  style={{
    height: 174,
  }}
>
  <p>{title}</p>

  <p>{message}</p>

  {renderCardCtaButtons(listItem)}
</Col>
```

and `renderCardCtaButtons`:

```js
const renderCardCtaButtons = (record) => {
  return (
    <Dropdown
      dropdownRender={() => (
        <div>
          <Button
            icon={<EditOutlined />}
            size="small"
          />
          <DeleteButton
            onDelete={() => deleteTemplate({ variables: { id: record.id } })}
          />
        </div>
      )}
      placement="bottomRight"
    >
      <Button>
        <i className="fas fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
      </Button>
    </Dropdown>
  )
}
```

I tried using position `absolute` for Dropdown component and it doesn't seem to work, I am looking to achieve something as below:

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to achieve this. You can use Ant Design's layout components and add a second Col for the dropdown. The card component can have a span of 20 and the dropdown Col can have a span of 4 so that it takes up a small section of the page on the right side.

Something like this:

```
<Row>
    <Col
      span={20}
      className="bg-white border d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center flex-column"
      style={{
        height: 174
      }}
    >
      <p>title</p>

      <p>message</p>
    </Col>
    <Col span={4}>{renderCardCtaButtons()}</Col>
</Row>
```

You may want the screen space below the dropdown to be usable, in which case you can use absolute positioning:

```
<Col
  span={24}
  style={{
        height: 174
      }}
    >
      <p>title</p>

      <p>message</p>
      <div style={{
        position: 'absolute',
        top: '24px',
        right: '24px',
      }}>{renderCardCtaButtons()}</div>
</Col>
```

Take a look: https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-pascal-oqzz0g?file=/src/App.js:776-1191

Answer (score 0):

I would override the element styles that are handling placement. Basically, AntD calculates the position of the select and left-aligns the dropdown below it, using javascript to write the top and left coordinates on the dropdown.

First, to see the dropdown open so you can test your overrides, add this to the Select...

```
<Select
  open
  defaultOpen
  dropdownClassName="my-dropdown"
  ...(the rest of your stuff)
>
```

Then in your style sheet...

```
.my-dropdown {
  width: 440px !important; /* replace 440px with your value */
  left: unset !important;
  right: 96px !important; /* replace 96px with your value */
}
```

You need !important to override the inline styles written on the dropdown via AntD's javascript.

Don't forget to REMOVE "open" and "defaultOpen" before you commit to your repo.